# Apply filter just for an spefic role on a view in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-6

I need to know if there is a way in `drupal 6` to apply a **filter** in a `view` just for an specific role??

I got 2 roles, employee and manager, so I am using a content type field reference to my own view, so I want to apply some filter depending of current user role?

is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the view go to filter. Click add filter. Select the user from the select box of the filter. The filter options for users appear. From that select user:role and specify the user